# Form not sending data through Post

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, input

I am implementing a simple newsletter form using PHP and CodeIgniter as part of a big project.

My HTML code is as follows.

```
<form method="POST" action='http://sit.com/index.php/Users/subscribenews'>
<div class="input-group">
<input type="email" id="pkemailid" name="pkemailid">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit"> Go
</button>
</span>
</div><!-- /input-group -->
</form>
```

In my Controller, I am handling the value as

```
$emailid = $this->input->post('pkemailid');
```

When I do a var_dump of the $_POST variable, I get the following

```
array(0) { }
```

The biggest problem is that I am able to run this correctly on my WAMP Server on localhost but it does not work on the hosted server.

Interestingly, if I change the POST to GET, then it starts working.

Comment: Other forms work on your application? Or it is just this one that doesn't work?

Comment: I checked all the forms now. None of them is working. All the forms have method="POST". Surprisingly, this works on the WAMP Server on my local machine.

Comment: form name attribute?

Comment: What the `$_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']` var shows after you submit a form?

Comment: I dont find a CONTENT_TYPE when I do a var_dump($_SERVER).

Comment: I also did a var_dump($_GET) and I get an empty array. Just to be sure!

Comment: Are you sure php is enabled on your hosted server?

Comment: Yes. The action link is generated using php only dynamically.

Comment: All the code is in PHP...all UI is generated using PHP

Comment: I suggest you output phpinfo() on local, then on remote, and diff both to see what php config is the cause of the problem.

Comment: Is there any specific thing that I need to look into. Comparing the two outputs is time consuming and difficult.

Comment: Try using the codeigniter form helper http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: It is not an issue with CodeIgniter, as I mentioned earlier. If I change from POST to GET, it works correctly. It is the issue with the Post.

Answer (score 0):

this line

```
<input type="email" id="pkemailid" name="pkemailid">
```

try changing it to

```
<input type="text" id="pkemailid" name="pkemailid">
```

type="email" is html 5 only and i don't know for certain -- but codeigniter might not support html 5 form values.

===== edit

so my suggestion when you are at the hair pulling questioning reality stage of trying to find a bug - get a fresh new copy of codeigniter, install on your server, make sure you get the welcome page.
now make the simplest form possible and echo something out from the controller method to make sure that you are submitting the form to the correct method. Next add a hidden form field with a value, and echo out that value from your method.

If all that works, then its not your server you have bug in your original code. And if it doesn't work then you have an issue with the server.

Comment: Codeigniter 3.0.3 on my local machine (wampserver) works fine. As I mentioned, the type="email" is not an issue. When I change the method to GET and use the $this->input->get, everything starts working fine.

Comment: if its working on your local machine, but not on the server - then it has to be a configuration issue on the server. so double check your config, routes, htaccess, etc. also when testing always echo out something from the controller/method so you know its contacting the correct controller.

Comment: I have done the same. Controller routing etc is working fine. As I mentioned, when I change the method to GET and use the appropriate CodeIgniter methods ($this->input->get), everything works fine. But I would like to stick to Post for obvious reasons.

Comment: added some sanity check suggestions above.